# Error adding 'recipe' in Vagrantfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, vagrant, cookbook

I have tried multiple times without any luck to get this code to run in my `Vagrantfile`, and each time I get the following error message:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

chef solo provisioner:
* The following settings don't exist: add_recipe
```

Here is the section of code I am referring to:

```
config.berkshelf.enabled = true
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.add_recipe = 'apache2'
end
```

I've downloaded the latest version from [this site](http://downloads.vagrantup.com) (version 1.2.2) and installed the `.pgk` file on my Mac without error.

I've also made sure that I've successfully installed `chef-11.4.4`, and run this both with the Vagrant box running and not running... still get the same error.

I'm brand new to this technology, so any help and/or suggestions would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what does `vagrant --version` return on the command line - and does your Vagrantfile start with `Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|`?

Comment: Is there are difference between using `:chef_solo` and `"chef_solo"`? The Vagrant docs have it as "chef_solo" or is that just a mistake? http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `add_recipe` method is a regular method, not an accessor, i.e. it is *not* `add_recipe=`. Thus, you can add recipes by using this code:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.add_recipe 'apache2'
end
```

Consequently, you can call that multiple times to add additional recipes (or add them as additional parameters).

Comment: Wow... spent hours on this. Thanks so much!